# Wordpress custom template gives error 505

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a new page template for specific pages in wordpress, I am able to select that from wordpress pages template selection but when browsing to the page I get error 500 rest of the site is working fine. Website is hosted on CDN and using W3 Total Cache plugin.

Below is the wordpress page template code:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: PackageDetails */
get_header(); ?>
<div class="container hds-custom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grey-bg clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        the_post();
                        the_content();
                    }
                }?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php $page_images =& get_children( array ( 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ));
                 if ( empty($page_images) ) { ?>
                 <h2>BOOKING AND RESERVATION (24/7)</h2>
                 <p>MOBILE NO: <a href="tel:+123456798">123456798</a> / <a href="tel:+123456798">123456798</a></p>
                 <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="552" title="Booking &amp; Reservation"]')?>
                 <div class="alert alert-warning mt-1 mb-1">
                 Important note / Cancellation / Amendment / Refund policy:
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, quam.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer('inner'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: PackageDetails 
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div class="container hds-custom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grey-bg clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        the_post();
                        the_content();
                    }
                }?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php $page_images =& get_children( array ( 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ));
                 if ( empty($page_images) ) { ?>
                 <h2>BOOKING AND RESERVATION (24/7)</h2>
                 <p>MOBILE NO: <a href="tel:+123456798">123456798</a> / <a href="tel:+123456798">123456798</a></p>
                 <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="552" title="Booking &amp; Reservation"]')?>
                 <div class="alert alert-warning mt-1 mb-1">
                 Important note / Cancellation / Amendment / Refund policy:
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, quam.</li>
                </ul>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer('inner'); ?>
```

you didnt close the `if ( empty($page_images) ) {`

Comment: good catch. defiantly could be a problem , :-) but why 500 ? this should be a simple PHP syntax error or exception.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error could have been caused due to multiple reasons. A corrupt `.htaccess` file is one of the common issues.

You could try to rename the file by logging in to the FTP server. Also, visit the `Permalinks` page in the `Settings` menu and save the page to generate the rewrite rules.

Also, try to deactivate the cache plugin and check if the page works fine.